# MPMoviePlayerController not visible in custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to initialise an `MPMoviePlayerController` in a custom `UIView`. I do hear the sound but no view. I think something is wrong with initialising the view. I tried it by implementing in the `ViewController`, then it does work.

Here my code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class CustomView: UIView {

var sponsor: Sponsors!

var videoContainer = UIView()
var videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    //Init
    layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    //VideoContainer
    videoContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    //Adding the views
    addSubview(videoContainer)
    videoContainer.addSubview(videoPlayer.view)        
}

//MARK: InitCoder
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

//MARK: AddDataToView
func addDataToView(sponsor: Sponsors) {

    //VideoPlayerx
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie5", ofType:"mov")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    videoPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    videoPlayer.prepareToPlay()
}

//MARK: LayoutSubViews
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()        

    //VideoContainer
    videoContainer.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, frame.size.width - 16, 219)

    //Video
    videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, frame.size.width - 16, 219)
    videoPlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set frame and add subview ***after*** create `videoPlayer` object. In `addDataToView` you init `videoPlayer` again so every settings before that are cleared.